# summation syntax for defining conditions and solving

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, summation

I am trying to generate datasets for which specific conditions related to the grand mean, group means, and differences among these values hold. I had tried in R, but was hoping that using Mathematica summation notation and Reduce[] would give more explicit outputs, versus my guess-and-check in R.

For example, for a polynomial of four additive terms: x^4 + 6*x^2*y^2 + 4*x*y^3 + y^4, (A+B+C+D), I want to generate a dataset with 10 groups of 100 individuals each, such that the third term predominates. I had done Reduce[C/A > 1 & C/B > 1 & C/D > 1] to get general conditions on x and y. However, as I mentioned, the terms are actually sums, and the third and fourth terms are, respectively, for example:

$4 \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^{n_{i}} (\overline{y_{i \bullet}} - \overline{y_{\bullet \bullet}}) (y_{ij} - \overline{y_{i \bullet}})^3$

and

$\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^{n_{i}} (y_{ij} - \overline{y_{i \bullet}})^4$

where $y_{ij}$ is individual $i$ in group $j$, $\overline{y_{\bullet \bullet}}$ is the grand mean, and $\overline{y_{i \bullet}}$ is the mean of a group. I'd like to make use of this summation notation to output a set of values that satisfy the condition that the third term predominates. For example, C/D > 1:

Reduce[$\frac{4 \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^{n_{i}} (\overline{y_{i \bullet}} - \overline{y_{\bullet \bullet}}) (y_{ij} - \overline{y_{i \bullet}})^3}{\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^{n_{i}} (y_{ij} - \overline{y_{i \bullet}})^4} > 1$]

but generating a list of $i$ values that satisfy the condition. Is there syntax for this kind of Reduce[], and data generation, in Mathematica? I am not familiar with how to transform the dot notation into something interpretable by Mathematica.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for the "dot" and summation notation: If you have `Y = Array[y, {10, 100}];` then the list of group means $(y_{1,\bullet},\dotsc,y_{k,\bullet})$ can be obtained by

```
groupmeans = Mean /@ Y
```

And

```
mean = Mean[groupmeans]
```

as well as `Mean[Mean[Y]]` equals the overall mean.

$4 \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^{n_{i}} (\overline{y_{i \bullet}} - \overline{y_{\bullet \bullet}}) (y_{ij} - \overline{y_{i \bullet}})^3$

Can be expressed as

```
c = 4 (groupmeans - mean).Total[(Y - groupmeans^3), {2}]
```

and

$\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^{n_{i}} (y_{ij} - \overline{y_{i \bullet}})^4$ is obtained by

```
d = Total[(Y - Mean[Mean[Y]])^4, {2}]
```

But I don't know what you want to do with `Reduce`. With so many unknowns, you are bound to make yourself unhappy. `FindInstance` might be more helpful. A possible syntax would be

```
FindInstance[c > d, Flatten[Y]]
```

but I did not wait for an answer to be returned.

Comment: I was using Reduce to find the general conditions on x and y for which C/D & C/B & C/A. The only constraints I have been thinking of for the $i$ would be that they are positive and real. Very interesting about the FindInstance syntax. I assume it could work then as FindInstance[c>d && c>a && c>b, Flatten[Y], Reals], assuming $a$ and $b$ are also formulated as you suggest, above. I will try this on my computer that has Mathematica. Thanks very much for these suggestions.